# Firebase Cloud Functions onCreate object undefined when creating a counter

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have root collection called `dashboard` and inside it I have a document called `totalUserCountry`. In this document I have a property with a bunch of country names. The value for each is a number.

The idea is for the function to run every time a new user gets added to the DB and **ADD 1** to the total.

However, I'm getting an error.  Here is my code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import admin = require('firebase-admin');

const db = admin.firestore();

export const onAddUser = functions.firestore.document('users/{userID}')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        let snapCountry = snapshot.get('country');
        snapCountry.toLowerCase();

        return db.runTransaction(async transaction => {
            const dashboardPath = db.collection('dashboard').doc('totalUserCountry');
            const dashSnap = await transaction.get(dashboardPath);
            const dashTotalUserData = dashSnap.data();
            const changes = { snapCountry: dashTotalUserData.snapCountry + 1 };
        })
    });
```

The error I get is

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

This occurs for the `dashTotalUserData` on the `const changes = { snapCountry: dashTotalUserData.snapCountry + 1 };` statement.

Any tips or advice?

Comment: which object is throwing you that line?

Comment: Hey @andresmijares the `dashTotalUserData` on the `const changes = { snapCountry: dashTotalUserData.snapCountry + 1 };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data()` can return `undefined` if the `dashSnap` snapshot doesn't exist.

So you should adapt your code along these lines:

```
  if (dashTotalUserData) {
    const changes = { snapCountry: dashTotalUserData.snapCountry + 1 };
    //....
  }
```

---

In addition, note that you need to return the promise returned by the `update()` method in your transaction, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions.

In your current code there is no update with the incremented value.

---

Finally, if I understand correctly, by building an object as follows:

```
const changes = { snapCountry: dashTotalUserData.snapCountry + 1 };
```

you plan to update the value of the field with the name corresponding to the `snapCountry` value, in the `totalUserCountry` document.

Note that this object will update the `snapCountry` field and not a country field named `usa` or `belgium` or `france`, etc.

If this understanding is the correct one, you should use the [square-bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors), as follows:

```
let changes = {};
changes[snapCountry] = dashTotalUserData.snapCountry + 1;
```

Comment: Yeah, I did add the `transaction.update()` method. You're right, it's writing `snapCountry` instead of the country name. Anyway around that?

Comment: See the update: you should use the square-bracket notation

Comment: THANK YOUUUU! That worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Firestore actually natively supports an [atomic increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-increment), so you don't need to do the transaction at all, and this can be significantly simpler (and more efficient, since the update entirely happens server side!).

Instead of returning the entire `db.runTransaction` block, you can just do this:

```js
...
        snapCountry.toLowerCase();

        const dashboardPath = db.collection('dashboard').doc('totalUserCountry');
        return dashboardPath.update(snapCountry,
            admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1));
    });
```

This code also avoids your current problem where the field might not exist, as increment will create the field at the value passed to increment (e.g. assumes it was previously zero if it doesn't exist).

Of course, Firestore also has a scaling limit of only one update per document per second, so as your application scales up, this counter document will start to get hammered pretty hard.

Indeed, Firestore documents an entire [solution for distributed counters](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/counters) that shards the increments over many documents, and then aggregates the result out of all of the documents when it is read.  Over the long term, something like this is much more scalable than incrementing a single field in a single document.